# String formatting in Java Scanner class

Tags: java, string, formatting

```
Scanner i=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
int in=i.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter an floating point number: ");
double d=i.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String str=i.next();

System.out.printf("%s%n,Sum of%2d and %.2f is %.2f%n",str,in ,d,in+d);
```

My problem is with formatting the String I enter through Scanner. I was trying to enter "Result is", but printf() seems to see only the "Result" part of string, so what is the command for blank space? thx

Comment: `i.nextLine(); //To avoid new line character.....
then change this line ....String str=i.nextLine();`

Comment: i.next() gets the next word. you probably want nextLine right?

Comment: When you change `next()` to `nextLine()`, be aware of this: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/5221149).

Comment: @SanketMakani On the contrary; answers should be in answers, not comments. If it's a dupe then it should be marked as a dupe. Embedding answers in comments makes it harder for people who come in the future to actually see the answer.

Comment: That way i will just skip Scanner entry and go right to printf(). Im wondering  how to manipulate String via Scanner. So when "Enter a string :" part comes i can enter "Result is" and get in output "Result is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possible solutions, but I believe the following will give you consistent behavior with the other inputs:

```
System.out.println("Enter an floating point number: ");
double d = i.nextDouble();
i.skip("((?<!\\R)\\s)*"); // skip whitespace, stopping after any newline

System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String str = i.nextLine();
```

This approach would allow you to enter all the inputs on a single line, if so desired.

For example:

> 1 1.2 Result is

However if you really intend for your users to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after every input, then it would be most consistent to read all the inputs with Scanner's nextLine() method, then parse as needed (using Integer.parseInt, etc).

---

**Java 9**

Due to a bug in Java 9, the atomic grouping `(?> ... )` must be added around the linebreak matcher `\R`. See bug report [JDK-8176983](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176983) for details.

```
i.skip("((?<!(?>\\R))\\s)*"); // skip whitespace, stopping after any newline
                              // Compatibility Note: Java 9 safe use of \R
```

This code will also work fine and not cause any problems if used for Java 8, so actually I recommend you use this workaround version in your code just to be on the safe side (e.g. if someone may copy/paste or set target to a different JDK).

---

**Java 7 and earlier**

The linebreak matcher `\R` is available in Java-8 or later. Prior to that version, you would have to use the "equivalent" pattern `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` however to work as a true equivalent it actually must be wrapped in the atomic grouping `(?> ... )`. See documentation bug report [JDK-8176029](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8176029) for details.

```
i.skip("((?<!(?>\\u000D\\u000A|[\\u000A\\u000B\\u000C\\u000D\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]))\\s)*"); // skip whitespace, stopping after any newline
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, can you show a simpler pattern without the workaround for the Java 9 bug which is now fixed?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException ok, I have gone with your suggestion and edited accordingly. However, I actually recommend you use the Java 9 workaround version in your code just to be on the safe side (e.g. if someone may copy/paste or set target to a different JDK).

Answer (score 1):

Even I encountered this problem few days ago where I had to input a new line right after I asked for a int or double. I solved it by using this -

```
int j=scan.nextInt();
double f=scan.nextDouble();
scan.skip("\n");
String str=scan.nextLine();
```

"scan is the name of my Scanner object".

See, here I used `scan.skip("\n);` because when you enter a number it consumes only that number and not the end of line. Therefore `scan.skip("\n")` skips that line which is still present in the buffer and hence, when we scan again it starts from a new line and we get the desired string.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is with formatting the String I enter through Scanner. I
>   was trying to enter "Result is", but printf() seems to see only the
>   "Result" part of string

**change this:**

```
String str=i.next();
```

**to this:**

```
String str=i.nextLine();
```

`next()` will only return what comes before a space. On the other hand  `nextLine()` returns the input including space between the words.

Comment: No need to answer this type of questions which could be solved in comments only. Just don't answer everything for some points. :/

Comment: if there was a newline after the double, you should consume that first

Answer (score 0):

ok fine you can make a trick like that, just add new string ang print that

```
String str=i.next();
  String strNew=str;
```

Comment: That doesnt solve problem just skip  to output , this part here is problem System.out.printf("%s%n,Sum of%2d and %.2f is %.2f%n",str,in ,d,in+d); That '%s' command formats string i should enter via Scanner class so problem is Scanner sees only entire string as i sad ,for instance via Scanner i enter "Result is" but output is only "Result".so how i solve that.How i manipulate String in Scanner so everything shows up.

Comment: see the answer now @Yurodivi

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
String[] str;
Scanner i=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
str=i.nextLine().split("");
System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
int in=i.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter an floating point number: ");
double d=i.nextDouble();

for(int k=0;k<str.length;k++){
    System.out.print(str[k]);
}
System.out.printf("Sum of%2d and %.2f is %.2f%n", in, d, in+d);
```

This clearly solve your answer,and if you want to write string like ("Hello  Dude  Coder") then this code gives you out put with all whitespace without any skip.

Comment: Yes, but how does this compare to other answers, specifically the answer that's been accepted?