# Java split string with '\r\n', '\r' or '\n' and keep it with preceding substring

Tags: java, regex

My input string contains mixed type of line separators including  '\r\n', '\r' or '\n'. I want to split the string and keep the line separator with the substring that precedes it. I followed two postings below

[How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

[Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

and come up with something like:

```
String input = "1 dog \r\n 2 cat";
String[] output = input.split( "(?<=((\\r\\n)|\\r|\\n))")));
```

the output is `["1 dog\r", "\n", " 2 cat"]`, however the desired output is `["1 dog\r\n", " 2 cat"]`.

If I change the input to either `String input = "1 dog \r 2 cat";` or `String input = "1 dog \n 2 cat";`, my code can produce desired output. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your result `["1 dog\r", "\n", " 2 cat"]` because your pattern uses an alternation which will match either `(\r\n)` or `\r` or `\n`.

When `\r\n` is encountered in the example string, the lookbehind assertion will be true after `\r` and will split for the first time.

Then the lookbehind assertion will be true after `\n` and will split for the second time.

What you might do is use `\R` in the positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is a [unicode newline sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
String input = "1 dog \r\n 2 cat";
String[] output = input.split("(?<=\\R)");
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/TijHYB)

Another option to fix your regex is to make it an [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html):

```
(?<=(?>\\r\\n|\\r|\\n))
```

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/FOAdby)

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496138/5424988), when the `\r` is matched in the lookbehind using an atomic group, the following `\n` is also matched.

Comment: Very nice answer! Using `\R` is better than my solution! +1

Comment: I think this answer would look better if you explain the reason why OP regex failed to work.

Comment: @Allan thank you, I have reused a part of your `printASCII` in the Java demo to list the characters if that is ok with you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a fair point, I have added an explanation about the OP regex.

Comment: Yeah, but why `\R` works is probably more interesting, and the answer to why `\R` works will also show OP how to fix their regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: sure go ahead! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following regex:`(?<=\\r\\n|\\r(?!\\n)|\\n)` to split your string it will work as intended.

What is happening with your regex is that when `\r\n` is encountered, the lookbehind assertion will be true `(?<=\r)` and it will split the string just after `\r`.

This is why I have added a negative lookahead `(?!\n)` after `\r` to enforce that the character after `\r` is not `\n`. This will prevent the split between `\r` and `\n` and keep it as a whole.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/H6PNmY/1/ (where I have replaced `\r` by `a` and `\n` by `b` for readability)

When you put this back in your code:

```
String input = "1 dog \r\n 2 cat, 1 car \r 2 planes, 1 apple \n 2 peaches";
String[] output = input.split("(?<=\\r\\n|\\r(?!\\n)|\\n)");

for(int i=0; i<output.length; i++)
{
  printASCII(output[i]);
  System.out.println("===");        
}
```

with `printASCII` defined as:

```
public static void printASCII(String in)
{
    for(int i=0; i<in.length(); i++)
        System.out.println("The ASCII value of " + in.charAt(i) + "  =  " + (int)in.charAt(i) );
}
```

It gives you the following output:

```
The ASCII value of 1  =  49
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of d  =  100
The ASCII value of o  =  111
The ASCII value of g  =  103
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 
  =  13
The ASCII value of 
  =  10
===
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 2  =  50
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of c  =  99
The ASCII value of a  =  97
The ASCII value of t  =  116
The ASCII value of ,  =  44
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 1  =  49
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of c  =  99
The ASCII value of a  =  97
The ASCII value of r  =  114
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 
  =  13
===
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 2  =  50
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of p  =  112
The ASCII value of l  =  108
The ASCII value of a  =  97
The ASCII value of n  =  110
The ASCII value of e  =  101
The ASCII value of s  =  115
The ASCII value of ,  =  44
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 1  =  49
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of a  =  97
The ASCII value of p  =  112
The ASCII value of p  =  112
The ASCII value of l  =  108
The ASCII value of e  =  101
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 
  =  10
===
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of 2  =  50
The ASCII value of    =  32
The ASCII value of p  =  112
The ASCII value of e  =  101
The ASCII value of a  =  97
The ASCII value of c  =  99
The ASCII value of h  =  104
The ASCII value of e  =  101
The ASCII value of s  =  115
===
```

That shows that the EOL characters are properly kept as you have requested.

> **ASCII table:** https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.networkcomm/conversion_table.htm