# What do I write in place of "scanner.skip()" statement?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

```
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

    int q = scanner.nextInt();
   scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

What is the use of this `skip()` method?

Can I replace it with another method to get the same result?

Comment: Your current code will not compile as it doesn't contain scanner declaration. But skipping line separator is one of solutions to problem described at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: *"What is the use of this above .skip() method?"* Read the javadoc: [`skip(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip-java.lang.String-). --- *"Would i replace with another method to get the same result?"* Don't know why you're asking for different method doing same thing, so difficult to answer, but javadoc shows example: `skip(Pattern.compile("\\R?"))`.

Comment: If you want to skip whitespace, stopping after any newline, then try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42471816/7098259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's read the docs for [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)):

> Skips input that matches a pattern constructed from the specified string.

So `skip` tells the scanner to not read some parts of the user input, and continue after those parts. Here, your pattern matches a Windows new line character `\r\n`, or one of these...

- U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
- U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
- U+0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)

...if such a pattern exists.

Why does the programmer write this? A possible explanation is to avoid the next call to `nextLine` returning an empty string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) for why this happens.

> Would i replace with another method to get the same result?

You could call `skip(Pattern.compile("..."))`, but really it's just another overload of the same method. The closest to what you are doing is probably `nextLine`, which uses a similar pattern to yours.